# (DIALOGFLOW) External webhook, How to set parameters in json and fill with webhook without working with session ID

Tags: dialogflow-es

I need to send via json some data and in the next call to my webhook retrieve this data to do some workflow into my application. I'm trying to get rid of session ID to set up a context, so any hint?